# How can I only show certain cards/notifications on a specific device?

Tags: calendar, google-now

I have a couple of Android devices - a HTC One as my phone and a Nexus 7 as a tablet. Both devices have Google Now on them and the Calendar application.

I got my phone first, and set up a variety of notifications, such as Google Now telling me approximately when I need to set off to get to work, and an entry in the Calendar application for various notifications like meetings, etc.

Now that I have my tablet, I'm finding that both devices are giving me the same notifications. Is it possible to filter/only show certain notifications on one device? If so, how would I achieve this?

Comment: The latest update to google calender has 'synchronised notification dismissals across devices' enabled. So, once dismissed in one device it will not show on others. But, this will not help in duplication of the notifications.

Comment: Is that functionality only available when both devices are running the version of calendar that comes with kitkat?

Comment: Google calander is available in [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar&hl=en). It is not part of KitKat update. It should be installed on both the devices. AFAIK, it has some limitations on HTC devices.